# Extract WAV header on javascript frontend (ReactJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, wav, node-streams

I'm trying to analyze a file I'll be uploading from react, I need to know if it can be uploaded based on several factors.

I found https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-wav
It works great on nodejs and I'm trying to use it on react. The sample creates a readable stream and pipes it to the wav reader.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var wav = require('wav');

var file = fs.createReadStream('track01.wav');
var reader = new wav.Reader();

// the "format" event gets emitted at the end of the WAVE header
reader.on('format', function (format) {
  //Format of the file
  console.log(format);
});

file.pipe(reader);
```

Using FilePond controller I'm able to get a base64 string of the file. But I can't figure out how to pass it to the reader

this is what I have so far on ReactJS:

```
        var reader = new wav.Reader();

        reader.on('format', function (format) {
          //Format of file
          console.log('format', format);
        });

        const buffer = new Buffer(base64String, 'base64')
        const readable = new Readable()
        readable._read = () => { } 
        readable.push(buffer)
        readable.push(null)

        readable.pipe(reader)
```

But I get Error: bad "chunk id": expected "RIFF" or "RIFX", got "u+Zj"

Since this file works on NodeJS with the same lib is obvious I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT:

this was a problem with my Base64 string, this method works if anyone needs to analyze a wav on the frontend

Comment: Why could you not use the [Web Audio API](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/)? It has had widespread browser support for 4-5 years.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Web Audio API, let me give it a try, thanks a lot for the info @DanNagle